# Question about browser events and HTMLElement.click()

Tags: javascript, dom-events

HTMLElement.click() seems to do what I would expect it to in some situations, but not others. For example on [this medium page](https://medium.com/s/story/facebook-is-just-like-the-nsa-22c43f236ff5),

```
document.body.querySelectorAll('.js-notificationsButton')[0].click()
```

will open a dropdown just like clicking that button would, but something like:

```
document.body.querySelectorAll('.js-actionMultirecommendButton')[0].click()
```

does not seem to produce the same effect that clicking that button would. I feel like I'm missing something when it comes to browser events, I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I would use the console and log out the event.target to make sure your targeting the right element.

Comment: Lots of possible reasons

Comment: I just pasted "document.body.querySelectorAll('.js-actionMultirecommendButton')[0].click()" into the console in Chrome on the Medium page you linked, and when I did the Medium login modal popped up. So it seems like it's working, at least in my browser.

Comment: @emmzee hmm, I was actually targeting the 'clap' button, which can also be targeted with .clapButton. The modal didn't show for me. I have a suspicion that it has to do with the event's isTrusted property, but I'm not sure. It doesn't really matter, I was just curious why it wouldn't work on certain buttons.